# Can I call a webservice from a Controller Action in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-2

Can I call a webservice from a Controller Action in ASP.Net MVC?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    PersonObject person = new Person("Sam");
    //Call a webservice which is located in the same app under /Services/General.asmx/WebMethod and pass it person
}
```

Basically I want to do this from my Action...

```
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Services/General.asmx/WebMethod",
                    data: JSON.stringify(DTOInternetPricing),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(res) {
                    },
                    error: function(res) {
                    }
                });
```

Comment: What kind of web service? Do you mean that your controller action is your web service? What are you calling it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the web service is part of the same application you may not need to call it as a web service at all, you could just use it's classes as normal objects, methods, etc.  ie just call the logic directly through code.

Answer (score 2):

In order to call a web service in C# you need to generate a client proxy from the WSDL. You need to [add a service reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic6) and use the generated proxy to consume the service.